# PowerBI Deneb room occupancy heatmap visualization

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

I have table

| country | site | space | Date | Hour_in_day | PeopleCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | NY | RoomA | 2023-10-03 | 0 | 10 |
| USA | NY | RoomA | 2023-10-03 | 1 | 15 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| USA | NY | RoomA | 2023-10-03 | 23 | 5 |

and I qwrite this Deneb code for show as heatmam I want in Y axe days in month, in X axe hour in day and in data bricks sum of PeopleCOunt

```
   {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "name": "webex_unpivot"
  },
  "mark": "rect",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "Hour_in_day",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "title": "Hour of the Day"
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "Date",
      "type": "temporal",
      "title": "Date"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "PeopleCount",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "legend": {
        "title": "People Count"
      },
      "scale": {
        "scheme": "viridis"
      }
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Hour_in_day", "type": "ordinal", "title": "Hour"},
      {"field": "Date", "type": "temporal", "title": "Date"},
      {"field": "PeopleCount", "type": "quantitative", "title": "People Count"}
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "axis": {
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "titleFontSize": 14
    },
    "legend": {
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "titleFontSize": 14
    }
  }
}
```

but this not works properlly, it shows me :

[image: my deneb vega lite result]

But I expecting something like this:

[image: expected result]

And if is possible add number of people count in each brick i will be very happy :)

Comment: Can you share a sample .pbix with data?

Answer (score 1):

Your `"data": { "name": ...}` should be set to `"dataset"` and not `"webex_unpivot"`. Per the [Deneb doc](https://deneb-viz.github.io/dataset):

> Even though this is passed through from Power BI, a specification
> needs to contain a reference to the named dataset, otherwise the
> values cannot be encoded when the specification is parsed. You should
> always ensure that a specification contains the following content for
> this to work:

```json
{
    ...
    "data": { "name": "dataset" }
    ...
}
```

Then you pass fields to the visual.
[image]

See the [Simple Worked Example](https://deneb-viz.github.io/simple-example) if you need help.